# Verilator, turn off linting for a file

Tags: verilog

Using verilator for linting, how can I turn off linting for one of my verilog files.

The [manual](http://www.veripool.org/projects/verilator/wiki/Manual-verilator) states that a configuration file with the following context can be used for this cause

```
`verilator_config
lint_off -file "dont_lint_me.v"
```

Where do I provide this configuration file as an input to verilator? Do I include it in one of my other verilog files (won't my (non-verilator) compiler and synthesizer be angry with this code)?

The manual also states:

> Take remaining text up the the next `verilog mode switch and treat it
>   as Verilator configuration commands.

What does `verilog mode switch` mean?

Right now I am invoking verilator with `verilator --lint-only linechecker.v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the configuration file in your Verilator command. Per the Verilator manual http://www.veripool.org/projects/verilator/wiki/Manual-verilator, just create the file with the configuration options, and name it something such as config.vlt (their recommended extension, but it doesn't matter).  Then just add it to your Verilator call, such as `verilator --lint-only linechecker.v config.vlt`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had tried to find a flag similar to `-F`